# Entering simulation parameters with default values

Tags: c++, user-input

I'm writing a program that requires the user to enter several parameters for a simulation, but most of the time they will be entering the same values each time so I want there to be some sort of default value so they can just press enter and that value will be used.

the prompt will look something like this:

```
Enter Some Parameter [15]:
```

so they can enter any number they want, or just press enter to use 15.

this is what I have so far

```
parameter = cin.get();
if(parameter == '\n')
    parameter = defaultValue;
```

it works, but only for the first digit and I also end up with a char cast to whatever type the parameter I'm working with is rather than the actual value that the user entered.

I would use

```
cin >> parameter;
```

but that doesn't let me use a default value in the way I described.

Does anyone know a way I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can try using string instead of char, for example:

```
std::string s;
getline( cin, s );
if( s.empty() ) // user pressed enter
     s = defaultValue;
```

This will work not for the first digit, but for the entire line

Comment: If you edit `if(s == "")` to `if(s.empty())` and avoid an unnecessary temporary, i'll upvote :)

Comment: @Armen: Ok, I will optimise it :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use cin.getline().  If they input a valid parameter, then update the parameter; otherwise just use the default.